# Docker container not using NordLayer VPN while connecting to internet

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-network

I want my local docker container to connect to my MongoDB Atlas. But it seems like when I connect to NordLayer VPN, the container is not taking Nord's static IP which we have reserved and whitelisted on Atlas.

If I do "curl [https://ipinfo.io/ip"](https://ipinfo.io/ip%22) from the container, it shows some random public IP, and if I do "What is my IP?" on google then it shows the Nord's static IP, which suggests that the container is not using VPN to go over the internet but regular browsing uses VPN IP.

I have read and implemented many posts but nothing as of now has worked for me.

Version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I get below error when I am attempting to connect:
Connection Error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

FYI:- The same setup works on Mac

Comment: Hard to troubleshooting without knowing the random IP addresses returned by API.

Comment: $ nordlayer settings set

Select setting to change:
1: VPN Protocol
2: Auto-connect
3: Always connect to
4: ThreatBlock
Select [number]: 1



Available values for VPN Protocol
1: Automatic
2: IKEv2/IPSec
3: OpenVPN TCP
4: OpenVPN UDP
Select [number]: 4

Comment: You may want to try running your container with the option `--net=host`, see https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: The issue has been resolved after making protocol changes on the NordLayer. I have listed the steps that are required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved after changing the Nordlayer protocol tp OpenVPN UDP

$ nordlayer settings set

```
Select setting to change:
  1: VPN Protocol 
  2: Auto-connect 
  3: Always connect to 
  4: ThreatBlock 

Select [number]: 1 

Available values for VPN Protocol 
  1: Automatic 
  2: IKEv2/IPSec 
  3: OpenVPN TCP 
  4: OpenVPN UDP
```

Select [number]: 4